# How can I write embed code for discord.py in a cleaner way?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

I currently just write my code in one entire line.
I have tried putting it on multiple lines but it still looks very messy and takes a lot of space when doing huge embeds with long values and/descriptions
Like this:

````py
import discord

Embed = discord.Embed(title = "Ping", description = my ping is currently something very long and it will take a lot of space for me to write all this information down", colour = discord.Colour.blue())```
````

Comment: btw [PEP-8](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (python style guide) suggests `names_like_this` for variable names and `NamesLikeThis` for class names to avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 1):

First your code isn't valid as you missed a quote, but to answer your question, you can put the values into variables to clean the call up and to further make it slimmer split the string into multiple lines:

```
desc = ("my ping is currently something very long and it will "
        "take a lot of space for me to write all this information down")
blue = discord.Colour.blue()
Embed = discord.Embed(title= "Ping", description= desc, colour= blue)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```py
Embed = discord.Embed(
    title = "Ping",
    description = "My ping is currently something very long and it will" 
                  "take a lot of space for me to write all this information down",
    colour = discord.Colour.blue()
)
```